# Is it possible to store the float type results obtained from the code calculation in FLASH memory?

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc, progmem

I am using Attiny1616 with Microchip Studio.

I want to store the float type results obtained from the calculation of the code in FLASH memory.

I have looked into PROGMEM, but PROGMEM does not support the float data type.

So I tried to convert the float type result to char type data using `snprintf` or `dtostrf` and save it, but it did not work.

This is my C code.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    const char test[] PROGMEM = "Hello, world!";

    char buf[5] = "";
    float cal_result = 10.83;
    
    //dtostrf(cal_result, 5, 2, buf);
    snprintf(buf, 6, "%f", cal_result);

    const char out[5] PROGMEM = {buf[0],buf[1],buf[2],buf[3],buf[4]};
    
        while(1){   
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can write the byte representation of the float to flash. You are creating a string representation of the float which is not what you want.

Comment: @Takeru Tsuji, So `const float PROGMEM cal_result = 10.83f;` fails for you?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica he wants to write a value from a calculation during runtime, PROGMEM wont help. He will need to erase a flash sector then write the float to flash.

Comment: @Fredrik Perhaps so. Calculations can happen at compile time too as in `const float PROGMEM cal_result = 10 + 0.83f;`.

Comment: Do you really need to use float? It will be very inefficient to do calculations with floating point types on low end 8-bit MCU. Most calculations can be done in pure integer types with little bit of adjustment.

Comment: Your MCU does not have a FPU so all floating point will get calculated by software floating point libraries. That's super-inefficient, similar to using *printf family of functions. This little code you posted has likely eaten up some 90% of your AVR's resources. Don't use PC stuff when programming ancient microcontrollers. Or alternatively, pick a modern microcontroller instead.

Comment: The `PROGMEM` only applicable to classic AVR (i.e. older MCUs such at ATmega328 and old attiny series). For modern AVR such as ATtiny1616 (tinyAVR 1-series) that roll out since 2016, all you need to do is to declare the variable as `const` to keep the variable in the flash.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not possible with `PROGMEM`.

`PROGMEM` is a compiler directive that prevent to use `RAM` to store a constant value. Instead the program will read it directly from the flash each time it need it (I ignore optimizations here)

See 6.2 memory map on [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATtiny1614-16-17-DataSheet-DS40002204A.pdf)

- A variable will be stored in `0x3800 – 0x3FFF` range
- A `PROGMEM` constant value will stored in `0x8000 – 0xBFFF` range

---

If you want to store data computed during the program is running, you will have to use:

- eeprom (low space, quite easy to use), see [avr/eeprom.h](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__eeprom.html)
- flash (more space, difficult to use (can only be written by page, has a limited number of writing), dangerous to use (you can wipe out your program accidentally)

Comment: Is there any other way to write to Flash memory other than PROGMEM?

If there is a way, can you provide the URL or an example of the code?

Comment: @TakeruTsuji you will have to do some reading, but that is common when dealing with embedded development https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATtiny1614-1616-1617-Auto-DataSheet-DS40002021C.pdf

Comment: I read the datasheet, but I couldn't understand it very well.
I tried writing some code, but it doesn't seem to be able to write data to FLASH.
'''
CCP = 0x9d;
NVMCTRL.CTRLA = 0x06;
  
NVMCTRL_ADDR = 0x8E00;
NVMCTRL.DATA = 0xABCD;  
CCP = 0x9d;
NVMCTRL.CTRLA = 0x04;
'''